# updating values using asp.net with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my table

```
roomtype, number of rooms
Ac         10
```

I want to retrieve the value from the table and subtract the rooms by 1 and update the above table. How do i write the retrieval code in asp.net using c#. The updation code is below and Iam checking if the availiability of the rooms is >1 then and only then it will update and insert but it is not doing so. It directly executes the else part. Help me find the error.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string type = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string name = TextBox2.Text;
    string nop = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.ToString();
    int num = int.Parse(nop);
    string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HMSConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    string qry3 = "select * from availiability where RoomType=@type";
    SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(qry3, connection);
    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", type);
    cmd3.ExecuteReader();
    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd3);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {

        if ((int)dt.Rows[0]["no_of_rooms"] > 1)
        {
            string qry = "insert into RoomType values('" + type + "','" + name + "','" + num + "') ";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, connection);
            connection.Open();
            int g = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (g != 0)
                Label5.Text = "Reserved for" + name;
            connection.Close();

            string qry2 = "update availiability set RoomType=@type ,availiable_rooms=@av";
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(qry2, connection);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", type);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@av", dt.Rows[0]["no_of_rooms"] - 1);
            connection.Open();
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();

        }
    }
    else
    {
        label5.Text = "No Rooms Availiable in " + type;
    }
}
```

Comment: retrieval code ? I am sorry but i didn't understand what is your question about?

Comment: i want to retrieve a number of rooms from the table subtract 1 from it and then update the value in the table

Comment: you already have the retrieval code - `string qry3 = "select * from availiability where RoomType=@type";` `SqlDataReader reader = cmd3.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            
        }`

Comment: what kind of error are you getting?

Comment: @user2334012 Since i see it's a room reservation scenario, So i would like to ask do you want to update your table or insert new rows every time? I mean what i feel you want last record and then subtract 1 or 2 and insert a new row again and then show the updated `availability` ? Is  it so ?

Comment: @user2334012 What i feel personally is you should use a transaction here first update your room availability (subtract your room by 1 or any number) if update is successful then you should insert new `Record` or create an entry for reservation, Please correct me if i am in wrong direction.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Web Forms?

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: so what should  I do to make it prone from sql injections . I mean how do i write my queries

Comment: @user2334012 use parameterized query .

Comment: @DanielA.White Not extremely vulnerable i think.

Comment: i have used parametrized query but it said incorrect syntax near @type.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to write this from scratch (aka Web Forms).  While that's admirable, do you have an option to use a framework that's a little more geared to what you're trying to do?  For example, ASP.NET MVC w/ Entity Framework.  Or even Web API w/ Entity Framework.  Both support POST/DELETE/PUT/GET and everything is wired up for you so you don't need to worry about manually coding the queries, etc.  Entity Framework does all of the work for you.

But, if you can't, it seems that what you have should work.  It's a pretty simple problem to solve.  As you demonstrated above, simply update the Rooms to the new value.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string type = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string name = TextBox2.Text;
    string nop = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.ToString();
    int num = int.Parse(nop);
    string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HMSConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    string qry3 = "select * from availiability where RoomType=@type";
    SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(qry3, connection);
    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", type);
    cmd3.ExecuteReader();
    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd3);
    Dataset ds = new Dataset();
    ad.Fill(ds);
    if (ds ! =null)
 {  
    if (ds.Rows.Count > 0)
    {

        if ((int)ds.Rows[0]["no_of_rooms"] > num) //Check if rooms are available 
        {
            string qry = "insert into RoomType values('" + type + "','" + name + "','" + num + "') ";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, connection);
            connection.Open();
            int g = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (g != 0)
                Label5.Text = "Reserved for" + name;
            connection.Close();

            string qry2 = "update availiability set RoomType=@type ,availiable_rooms=@av";
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(qry2, connection);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", type);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@av", convert.toint32(ds.Rows[0]["no_of_rooms"]) - num);
            connection.Open();
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();

        }
    }
    }
    else
    {
        label5.Text = "No Rooms Availiable in " + type;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the updated code. It is showing errors in "dt.Rows[0]["no_of_rooms"] > 1" saying that an object type cannot be compared with an int. but on parsing this no_of_rooms to int the error remains the same. Here is the code.

Comment: Use `Convert.toInt32(dt.Rows[0]["no_of_rooms"]) >1` .

Comment: @user2334012 Sorry but i don't see updated code ? Can you update your question please ?

Comment: I have updated the code. Now Iam checking if the availiability of the rooms is >1 then and only then it will update and insert but it is not doing so. It directly executes the else part. Can you find the error.

Comment: @user2334012 Your `datatable` is empty. After declaring datatable you have to fill it, It's empty .

Comment: @user2334012 fill your dataset by `dataadpter`.